# jQuery ui draggable. Clone with shadow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to imitate this [image]

This is my draggable:

```
$( function() {
    $('#sidebar .question-constructor').draggable({
        connectToSortable:'#preview',
        scroll: false,
        helper : 'clone',
        cursorAt: { top: 56, left: 200 } 
    });
});
```

and my div

```
<div class="question-constructor" style="border-style:solid; border-width:5px;">
    <label for="textbox" style="display: inline-block;" >Question: </label>
    <input id="textbox" type="text" />
</div>
```

my current output is like this:
[image]

Its quite far to my goal. But for now I want to know how can I put a shadow in the **clone** of the draggable just like my goal image?

**UPDATE:**

I tried using this snippet:

`$('.question-constructor').animate({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });`

I placed it outside the draggable selector but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('.question-constructor').animate({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
```

Use this:

```
$('.question-constructor').css('boxShadow','4px 2px 17px 5px grey');
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use .css? If I'm going to use css I want to be reference by a class. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('.question-constructor').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#preview',
        scroll: false,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function (e, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).css('boxShadow', '0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)'); //change css 
        },
        cursorAt: {
            top: 56,
            left: 200
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/ndb8G/